# Why Chrome browser not supporting FormData(this) using Ajax script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-chrome

1. I am using Ajax script to post values to php file for document uploading
   purpose.
2. I had done this code in a page-template of wordpress.

**Below is my html script**

```
 <form id="apply_job" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="popUpSec" id="applyBox" style="display:none;">
      <div class="rows">
        <input type="file" class="inputFile" id="opn_file" name="opn_file" />
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
        
      <div align="center"><input value="Apply" type="submit"  class="subsBtn" /></div>
        
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

**And below is my Ajax script**

```
 jQuery("#apply_job").submit(function (event) {
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://example.com/file.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: new FormData(this),
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     processData:false,
     success: function(data)
     {
        alert(data); 
          
        if(data=="Mail sent successfully") {
          document.getElementById("apply_job").reset();
          hideAndShow('applyBox');
          return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**And below is the PHP script I am using**

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["opn_file"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['opn_file']['name']))){
    $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/'.$_FILES["opn_file"]["name"]);
 } else {
    echo $result = "No attachment found.";
    exit;
 }
```

I am using `$attachments` variable to send mail with attachments.

**My Problem:**

`$_POST` array and `$_FILES["opn_file"]["name"]` values are not getting to php files in Chrome browser. And the same code is working in Firefox.

If anything I am missing in explaining, please let me know.

**Question Edit Part**

I had seen the below content in the console part (Chrome browser)

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----ebKitFormBoundarycjW5QOMAnsUD7Y8f
Date:Thu, 17 Dec 2015 14:15:44 GMT
Server:xxxx
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Pingback:http://example.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
X-Varnish:498399885
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11509
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycjW5QOMAnsUD7Y8f
Cookie:_gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1724306164.1450332097
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/career-test/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Request Payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycjW5QOMAnsUD7Y8f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

------WebKitFormBoundarycjW5QOMAnsUD7Y8f--
```

I hope, This new changes might help to find any solution..

Comment: Since you are already using `jQuery` why don't you try to send your data by `serializing` the form with [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @xpy I had tried that too. But, no luck.  And also I tried with a static data too.. like `{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'Value2' }`. Nothing is works for me.  :(

Comment: I suspect that your problem may be somewhere else, are you sure your js code executes without errors? What does the console say? what does the `alert(data); ` say? Also, you can check in the `chrome developer`, on the `network` tab, you can review your requests to the server, is everything sent as it should?

Comment: Yes @xpy, Just now observed in console, a header line like `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfVvf10M2dFDfwRuf` What is boundary? is that a clue.

Comment: I honestly have no idea... What is the result of the request?

Comment: @xpy, Please check the `Question Edit part` in the question.. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Chrome add "C:\fakepath\" on the filename in the input type file value. So, in your PHP code, when executing the "move_uploaded_file", the destination path will be wrong. Just need to apply an str_replace

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
$name = str_replace( "C:\\fakepath\\", "", $name );
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```